# Intercept and Coefficient in Regression

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, regression

In regression model `we don't penalize the intercept (Lasso and Ride)` why it's so ? What does intercept significance.

Why `Over fitting model` tends to have large coefficient ?

Answer (score 1):

Ridge and LASSO are equivalent to using L1 and L2 regularization, respectively. Regularization helps reduce variance and avoid overfitting. So, your question is equivalent to asking, would penalizing the intercept help regularize the model and avoid high-variance? Penalizing the intercept would cause it to resist change, and leave it in its default position (probably zero or some small, randomly initialized value). However, there is no reason to assume that this random initialization has any meaning. Regularization of the other coefficients adds stiffness to the model, making the conceptual like less flexible and causes less twists and turns (lower variance). However, applying regularization to the intercept, just drags the point where the line crosses the y axis down, moving the geometry with no particular benefit. Or at least that is how I visualize it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation to what you said or provide a link to understand the same.